# How do Apes get their Omega 3s in the wild given so few plant sources? Are they able to convert it to DHA?

Tags: nutrition, digestion, diet

Given so few plant sources(around 6-7) of ALA, how do Apes get ALA in the wild?

Are they able to convert it into DHA in satisfactory amounts?

Comment: I am not sure they as much as a human, at least their brain is smaller afaik. and humans need is mostly for the membrane of brain cells. Another thought that from cardiovascular perspective you can compensate the missing omega-3 with omega-9. At least I have pretty good LDL/HDL ratio and I eat mostly omega-9 from olives instead of omega-3. We don't have sea nearby...